# Django STATIC_URL use within java script code not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, hyperlink

My problem is that I am using Django `STATIC_URL` within my java script code. My code works in my developing environment but when I upload it to pythonanywhere.com it's not working. I checked my code relative paths it's working but using STATIC_URL it's not working my code looks like this:

```
document.write("  <source data-src='{{STATIC_URL}}{{filename}}' type='video/mp4' >");
```

Comment: Is that in a .js file or is it javascript code written inside <script> tags in the html file?

Comment: its java script code written in <script> tags

Answer (score 3):

You should be using something like the following 
Import staticfiles in your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Then to access the static dir use 'static':

```
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

That will point to the static dir you have on the file system and the subdirectory 'my_app'.

So you would have:

```
document.write("  <source data-src='{% static "filename" %}' type='video/mp4' >");
```

Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/.